# External Js file does not validate my html form

Tags: html, validation

I did a code in html linked to an external Js file but it the JS code doesn't validate the form fields. Can anyone spot the problem please. I tried everything i could to get the JS to validate the form but it just wouldn't work. Below is the JS code:

```
<script>
    function validateMyForm() {
        var fname = document["myform"]["firstname"].value;
        var lname = document["myform"]["lastname"].value;
        var email = document["myform"]["email"].value;
        var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
        var pass = document["myform"]["password"].value;
        var passlen = pass.length;
        var confpass = document["myform"]["ConfirmPassword"].value;

        if (fname == null || fname == "") {
            alert("Please enter your First Name!");
            return false;
        } else if (lname == null || lname == "") {
            alert("Please enter a your Last Name!");
            return false;
        } else if (email == null || email == "") {
            alert("Please enter an email!");
            return false;
        } else if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= email.length) {
            alert("Please enter a valid email address!");
            return false;
        } else if (pass == null || pass == "") {
            alert("Please enter a Password!");
            return false;
        } else if (passlen < 4 || passlen > 15) {
            alert("Password needs to be to have a length of 4-15 characters");
            return false;
        } else if (pass != confpass) {
            alert("Passwords do not match!");
            return false;

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, please refer to this prior to asking another question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 

Please include what you have tried instead of saying you have "tried everything" It would also help to have your form HTML. 

Are you triggering the function on submit? Do you have a button that validates the form?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that you did not post your HTML, I am going to assume that you are not triggering your function.

In order for your function to work you need to trigger the form validation function. In order to do this, you will need to add `onsubmit="return validateMyForm()"` to your form tag. Make sure to include `return` before calling your function. [As shown here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp)

If there are problems with your code you see the errors using the inspector that is built into all web browsers. If you are using chrome you can access the inspector by pressing `Control+Shift+C`

Comment: I am new to this forum. Unfortunately, the message board won't allow me to post my html code

Comment: You have to do 4 spaces indentation in each line to make it show up as code